# choosing a specific object from an array

Tags: reactjs

I am sending all the props of a state from the main component to another one and in the child component, I want to show the exact post of an array by choosing one.

```
<Route
    path='/single/:id'
    render={(params) => <Single {...this.props} {...params} />}
/>

const {match,posts} = this.props
const id = Number(match.params.id)
const post = posts.find((post) => post.id === id)
console.log(post)//shows undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(id)` to make sure that it's defined correctly? Same for the content of `posts`

Comment: The most likely cases are: 1. posts is not the structure you expect. E.g. the `id` property is called `ID`. 2. The posts array is empty. 3. The id from params is not a number, then incorrectly parsed, and now is `NaN`. 4. The id does not exist inside the posts array.

Comment: hello, id is id in array, when I console.log(id) its show the correct of id, id is number also and when I console.log(posts) it is showing the state so it means that my state transfer right to child component

Comment: Did you make sure the `post.id` is the type Number like the `id` variable?